TypeORM can not order by on addSelect field
I have this code block:

async getReceiptsForTimeline(
    userId: string,
    getTimelineInput: GetTimelineInput,
): Promise<ReceiptCursorBasedPaginatedResult> {
    const { cursor, take = 10, direction = PaginationDirection.FORWARD, latitude, longitude } = getTimelineInput || {};

    const queryBuilder = this.receiptRepository.createQueryBuilder('receipt')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('receipt.owner', 'owner')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('receipt.business', 'business')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('receipt.receiptType', 'receiptType')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('receipt.userFolder', 'userFolder')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('userFolder.user', 'userFolderUser')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('receipt.images', 'images')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('receipt.lineItems', 'lineItems')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('business.addresses', 'businessAddresses', 'businessAddresses.location IS NOT NULL')
        .where('receipt.status = :status', { status: 'confirmed' })
        .andWhere('receipt.isPublished = true')
    // .andWhere('owner.id != :userId', { userId })

    if (latitude !== undefined && longitude !== undefined) {
        queryBuilder.addSelect(
            `ST_Distance("businessAddresses"."location"::geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude), 4326)::geometry)`,
            'distance'
        ).setParameters({ longitude, latitude });

        queryBuilder.addOrderBy('distance', 'ASC');
    }
    queryBuilder.addOrderBy('receipt.createdAt', 'DESC');

    const clonedQueryBuilderForPreviousPage = queryBuilder.clone();
    let hasPreviousPage = false;

    const promises = [];
    promises.push(queryBuilder.take(take + 1).getMany());

    if (cursor) {
        const cursorDate = new Date(cursor);
        if (direction === PaginationDirection.FORWARD) {
            queryBuilder.andWhere('receipt.createdAt > :cursor', { cursor: cursorDate });
            clonedQueryBuilderForPreviousPage.andWhere('receipt.createdAt < :cursor', { cursor: cursorDate });
        } else if (direction === PaginationDirection.BACKWARD) {
            queryBuilder.andWhere('receipt.createdAt < :cursor', { cursor: cursorDate });
            clonedQueryBuilderForPreviousPage.andWhere('receipt.createdAt > :cursor', { cursor: cursorDate });
        }
        promises.push(clonedQueryBuilderForPreviousPage.getCount());
    }

    console.log("queryBuilder.getSql()", queryBuilder.getSql());
    const [receipts, previousPageTotal] = await Promise.all(promises);

    const hasNextPage = receipts.length > take;
    hasPreviousPage = previousPageTotal > 0;

    const data = hasNextPage ? receipts.slice(0, take) : receipts;

    return {
        data,
        hasPreviousPage,
        hasNextPage
    };

queryBuilder.getSql() logs this into the console:
SELECT
    "receipt"."id" AS "receipt_id",
    "receipt"."ownerId" AS "receipt_ownerId",
    ...
    ST_Distance ( "businessAddresses"."location" :: geometry, ST_SetSRID ( ST_MakePoint ( 26, 41 ), 4326 ) :: geometry ) AS "distance" 
FROM
    "receipt" "receipt"
    LEFT JOIN "user" "owner" ON "owner"."id" = "receipt"."ownerId" 
    AND ( "owner"."deletedAt" IS NULL )
    LEFT JOIN "business" "business" ON "business"."id" = "receipt"."businessId" 
    AND ( "business"."deletedAt" IS NULL )
    ...
WHERE
    ( "receipt"."status" = 'confirmed' AND "receipt"."isPublished" = TRUE ) 
    AND ( "receipt"."deletedAt" IS NULL ) 
ORDER BY
    distance ASC,
    "receipt"."createdAt" DESC


When I try to run this query on my DB management tool, it returns the expected result. However, it does not return it in response to queryBuilder.getMany().
I tried not to add the queryBuilder.addSelect but directly tried ordering based on the ST_Distance("businessAddresses"."location"::geometry, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude), 4326)::geometry) , but it threw an unknown alias error.
While debugging, I noticed that TypeORM encapsulates my query with a distinctAlias query as follows:
SELECT DISTINCT
"distinctAlias"."receipt_id" AS "ids_receipt_id"
FROM
(
    ...
) "distinctAlias" 
ORDER BY
distance ASC,
"receipt_id" ASC
LIMIT 11


I must order the result with that PostGIS calculation. Can anyone help me? Thanks!
